# Can I listen to any event in eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am running eureka and spring boot for service discovery.

Can I extend it to have a event e.g. one of the instance is down, my spring boot shall listen to it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the javadoc, I could see [this event package](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.0.0.M1/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/event/package-summary.html) which includes different events. Maybe the [`EurekaInstanceCanceledEvent`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.0.0.M1/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/event/EurekaInstanceCanceledEvent.html) is the event you're looking for?